# Does thread compound (dope) over tape prevent this kind of leak?

Tags: plumbing

When applying pipe joint compound, a.k.a dope, does the application of tape (Teflon tape etc...) not hinder a chemical bond between the compound and the threads, or is does the compound merely serve as a filler, albeit one that withstands high pressure?

Here is a new threaded water fitting where I noticed a slow leak:

[image]

I have a suspicion that the problem here is too much tape (someone did this before me), and I will take it apart and redo.

But what's interesting is that it seems there is water escaping at *both* ends of the threaded connection. This suggests the water is traveling under the tape to the far end as well.

Could pipe compound over tape have avoided this? Does this not make the case for compound-only?

This question, [What goes on threads first: tape or dope?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21066/what-goes-on-threads-first-tape-or-dope) has answers either way, and comments arguing for or against each. It all seems based on valuable experience, but there is no mentioning of the science. And youtube videos on this topic go either way, or are indifferent about it.

To clarify the specific question in light of that and other similar questions: if the water is leaking under the tape, is compound -which goes over the tape per manufacturer's recommendation- the right remedy?

But I think the answer is in the comments: the taping is poorly done, and either it should be re-done, or it should be doped. No need to do both, this is an application failure, not the wrong choice of method.

Is this question a duplicate? No.

Other questions (see here and as linked in the comments), address when either of the two are required, yielding many contradicting answers.

My specific question asks about what happened here in my fitting (drops despite tape, no dope), could it be avoided with dope, and wouldn't dope alone be better than tape since tape is the point of failure here. And whether the tape would hinder a chemical or better compound bond (no it doesn't, a compound seal is not based on a chemical bond).

There are many valuable insights in the comments and in the answers, some reflect the sentiments and facts in previous questions and some are new.

Comment: As a non expert, I always thought you used one or the other, depending which one was handy.  With the dope you don't need to know which direction to wrap the tape, just brush it on.

Comment: Wahahaha! Oh no, next: the tape direction debate... Anyway, what you write is what I thought until I shopped around, and now I am none the wiser. I thought tape hinders the bond... Let's see what the answers say.

Comment: My plumber buddies always "double dope it" IE: Apply the sealing compound (dope) first, then a couple of wraps of teflon tape. I've done that and never had a leak.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What goes on threads first: tape or dope?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21066/what-goes-on-threads-first-tape-or-dope)

Comment: Or this? [When should pipe dope vs thread tape be used?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/when-should-pipe-dope-vs-thread-tape-be-used?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Or this? [When is pipe dope/tape needed?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36613/when-is-pipe-dope-tape-needed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I suspect you're right--too much tape. This would cause it to bunch up and push out rather than staying in place between the fittings.

Comment: It would be better if the picture showed more of the fitting on the left.  The teflon looks messed up outside the thread so could easily be messed up inside it.  If you take it apart, it's usually crystal clear what went wrong.  A good teflon tape job once removed should show smooth almost continuous tape well conformed to the grooves.  Too little tape and it won't fill the gap, too much and it will bunch up and also won't fill the gap.  Not everyone is aware that some threads are straight and some tapered.

Comment: For tapered threads that have been done up and undone, it can be tricky to get them to seal again.  If wrapped neatly and tightly in the correct direction and threaded together correctly, you can do up fittings well with more tape than the 3 wraps recommended/required for new fittings, and having done a fitting up successfully with too much tape, a person might do up more fittings less successfully due to inadequate attention to bunching.

Comment: @KH I'd like to upvote your comment in answer form.

Comment: @p2000 I'd like just a bit more information, perhaps disassembled pictures from OP, and I feel a proper answer should have a bit more information yet.

Comment: @KH yes please... btw, I am the OP. What do you need disassembled, I think you confirmed what I thought which is poor taping is all it is

Comment: Oh didn't realize because I recognised you.  Yeah, I'd shut off the water and unscrew the parts carefully using two wrenches or pairs of water pump pliers and take pictures of the now concealed teflon tape.  If it leaked once, I'll usually put it back together with tape and dope since the simplest solution is to re set it and see if it still leaks.  Even if you just put it right back together properly the pictures might be useful for future searchers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're supposed to use one or the other. If you're going to use both then apply the tape first. If you dope then wrap then I could foresee the tape being pushed out of the way before it gets gripped in the female threads.

Neither one is designed to produce a chemical bond, not sure where you got that idea from. These products aren't Loc-tite blue/red.

Both are designed to act as physical obstructions so that water cannot get through the threads. I don't think that using both hinders nor helps to stop leaks over using just one; proper material coverage and tightening are your best friends.

Some plumbers like to use both for whatever reason; old habits die hard I guess.

Maybe they've succumbed to some persistent inspector that likes to see both products applied so now it's a habit and propagated de facto. Here's an HVAC instructor that tells his class to ["apply mastic to the outside of flex duct to appease the inspector"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m1eRBXDM5I&t=655s). Obviously this example is HVAC but the common denominator is the same; the inspector.

I have success regardless of which method I use.

I have a particularly rusted galvanized line to which I ran PEX. The threaded brass transition leaks a tear-drop every so often but it's actually caked with enough rust/hard water that it no longer leaks. I may try switching out the pipe dope for tape whenever I have some time to spare.

Comment: According to Oatey: "Once the male threads are wrapped properly you can apply a coating of pipe joint compound over the thread sealant tape before assembling the joint."

Comment: @P2000 Well that's interesting. I have an old-ish jar of their dope so I'm gonna read it when I get home. Regardless, it says "Tape and joint compound **can** be used in conjunction with one another." There is no explicit recommendation to do both. However, if you choose to do both then they do suggest that the tape does go on first.

Comment: Just wondering if this is the same as shampoo, they double their sales by adding the word 'repeat'.  Does Oatey make tape also?

Comment: @crip659 I would bet they've received a fair share of phone calls on the situation that they decided to do their own testing and add it to the label. I wouldn't be surprised if their automated greeting included "Read the label for the tape+dope debate and hang up or press 4 to continue"

Comment: Oatey probably says that because some folks insist on using both. It makes no sense to me. Why wouldn't you want the thread compound to seal _to the fitting_, and not to the tape? It's like putting a flat washer under a lock washer.

Comment: @isherwood that flat washer debate is to me indeed the same thing. I think they have learned to tolerate people who insist on applying both. Just because it's possible does not make it necessary. So I am wondering if it actually reduces efficacy, or whether some degree of judgment is required per case.

Comment: @isherwood I wouldn't doubt if it is something that clueless inspectors have come to expect so plumbers abide just to pass inspection. Exhibit A: ["apply mastic to the outside of flex duct to appease the inspector"](https://youtu.be/3m1eRBXDM5I?t=655)

Comment: @P2000 See my comment above.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes that's the impression I'm getting on this topic. It could also be a spill-over from requiring curing compound on gas fitings. I believe code requires compound, fitters add tape (I don't understand why), and that has become the "new" inspection standard for water. I always thought tape would reduce the efficacy of curing compound.

Comment: @P2000 Like the old saying goes "If you want 7 different answers to something then just ask 3 people. If you want the right answer, consult the manual." Since the tape failed then try re-applying fresh tape per their instructions; make sure to wire brush all of the old tape out of the threads. You cannot blindly trust that the previous person did it right but it also looks nicer if you don't have a random dope joint when all others are tape. If it fails then try tightening the joint more. If it fails again then use pipe dope. If it fails again then tape-dope it. Lastly, try replacing the joint

Answer (score 1):

What really does work in conjunction with pipe dope is plumber's hemp. This is used widely in Europe, New Zealand,  and Australia, perhaps because they sometimes use parallel threads which cannot be sealed completely with dope alone. Plumber's hemp will also work with the tapered threads used in the US. I have never used hemp, but I intend to try it in the future, and I do not intend to scratch the male threads to hold the hemp in place.

There are numerous videos showing how to use plumber's hemp and they advocate different methods of use. Here is just one:

https://youtu.be/77QxXewSVbg

[image]

Comment: First I thought this was a joke... dope & hemp. There is something like this in North America, called pipe wick. Comes on a roll like dental floss or yarn, unlike a big blond hemp wig as shown in the video. Isn't hemp more for high temperature applications like heat & steam?

Comment: Modern pipe dope contains granules which replaces the need for hemp/twine/wick. I am pretty sure you have to buy a specific dope to be used with this string method which does not contain granules.

Comment: Yes, the paste contains no granules. It's pretty thick. Make sure you get the one specified for drinking water fittings, that one is non-toxic. I've never had a leak with that, it's very reliable, but a bit messy. There's a kind of tape that does the same thing, it's fiber impregnated with dope, called "atmo seal". It's excellent, faster, and less messy. Also you will need to scratch the male threads.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the real issue is too many fittings/leak points. It looks like they either could not find the proper pex to threaded fitting or used what they had on hand. Find the proper fitting and reduce the leak points.